# Submiting an app (game) for Facebook App Review

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

Can I submit an app for a review on Facebook without using any Facebook functionality? On the App Review page the button "Submit for a review" is inactive and wants me to add some items (e.g. user_likes, publich_actions etc), but I don't have/want this. I just want to publish it. Can it be done?

By the way, the app is a game and I want it published on Facebook Gameroom.

Comment: _“Can I submit an app for a review on Facebook without using any Facebook functionality?”_ - without _any_ Facebook functionality, there _is_ nothing to submit ...

Comment: But the game will not be seen by other users (except me) if I do not submit it for review. It is live in Gameroom, but I am the only one who can play it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting your game for Gameroom, you will need to submit the App Center Details via the App Dashboard.
As for the game itself, you cannot submit it via the App Dashboard, you should submit it via the [Gameroom submission form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/149706225508848).

> For your game to show up on Gameroom, please note that the following is required:
>
> - App Details reviewed and approved by us.
> - Game submitted for review and approved by us.
> - You have set the App status to live.
> - You have set the zip assets to be in push to production status.

You can find these details in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gameroom#contact).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I do try to submit via the submission form, but in that form I have on bullet point saying: "Under App Review, in the Approved items card, have you submitted App Details (Games Only) and received an approval?
Note: your app will be rejected if you have not completed this step." So that is the step that I am trying to accomplish. By the way in AppCenter Details they ask me to explain how I do Login in my game. The game is for gameroom, the user is already logged in as I understand, I don't need to log him in once again. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/listing/ You have to add it via +Product in your App Dashboard.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get what to add in my App DashBoard? I have everything added what I need.

Comment: In the App Dashboard, click on "+ Add Product" > App Center > Fill out the details. Under "App Center" you will also see "Review". Use that to submit the app details.

Comment: If you are developing a Gameroom native game, then you should not have to integrate login. You can perhaps add that to your notes for the submission.